# onStart method not working in primefaces dialog in IE8,9 versions

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, primefaces

I use primefaces dialog.In that dialog while clicking save button i used onStart method for validation using jQuery.It is working(calling the jQuery validation method) in chrome, firefox and latest version of IE but not working in IE8 and 9 versions.But i want to work in these versions only(IE 8,9).

Comment: Make sure your IE versions are **not** running in compatibility  mode

Comment: My IE is not running in compatibility mode.